# SQL query help (ambiguous column error) using select for multiple table queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having trouble with an 'Ambiguous column name' will really appreciate your help with this as I am stuck on this and don't understand. I am learning SQL

Basically I am trying to generate a student detail who fail the exam using multiple tables.

```
select 
    examDate, examLevel, examSubject, examResult, 
    studentID, studentFirstName 
from 
    completedExams, exams, student
where 
    (completedExams.examNo = exams.examNo) 
    and (completedExams.examResult = 'Fail')
```

Error:

> Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Ambiguous column name 'studentID'.

Comment: You need to learn about table aliases and how to use them with columns.  As a hint:  you are using them in the `where` clause.  Use them in the `select` clause too.

Comment: erm it might sound stupid but i absolutely have no idea, I wrote the code I am using, is it right? can u tell me how to do it?

Comment: You also should change the method of joining information together. I'm not sure who is teaching you to do it this way but it is an incredibly outdated method for joining tables.

Comment: m a beginner with database and SQL,  so just trying to learn how to do different queries and generate data from database

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First off your method for joining is hideously outdated. People were urged to stop doing this when ANSI came out with new standards back in 92. Your query should start off looking like this.

```
select 
    examDate,
    examLevel,
    examSubject, 
    examResult,
    studentID,
    studentFirstName 
from completedExams
inner join exams 
    on completedExams.examNo = exams.examNo
    and completedExams.examResult = 'Fail'
inner join student
    on student.studentID = CompletedExams.StudentID
```

Next lets talk about aliases. It is incredibly helpful to give your table an alias so you are not constantly typing `completedexams.` over and over. All you do is simply place the new name after the table name and you're golden.

```
select 
    examDate,
    examLevel,
    examSubject, 
    examResult,
    studentID,
    studentFirstName 
from completedExams as c
inner join exams  as e
    on c.examNo = e.examNo
    and c.examResult = 'Fail'
inner join student as s
    on c.studentID = s.StudentID
```

Now if the column exists in both databases you're going to have to apply that alias before the column that way the database engine knows which column you actually want. I don't know exactly which go where because I'm not connected to your database however here's an example anyway.

```
select 
    c.examDate,
    c.examLevel,
    e.examSubject, 
    e.examResult,
    s.studentID,
    s.studentFirstName 
from completedExams as c
inner join exams  as e
    on c.examNo = e.examNo
    and c.examResult = 'Fail'
inner join student as s
    on s.studentID = c.StudentID
```

Well I hope that helps. This has been introduction to sql or sql 101 with Zane.

Comment: Zane Appreciate your help. It did make sense to me now, I wasn't taught the inner join way I will practice it. Thanks a lot. P.S My name is also Zain :)

Answer (score 0):

your completedExams probably has a studentID as well.
so when you join both student and completedExam you will get two studentIDs in the join table.

You could try alliassing your tables to select the propper id

```
select student.studentId, ... from ...
```

As suggested in the comments as well, this is not a good way to join your tables. You should consider specifying the join column for the three tables

```
select student.studentId,... from completedExams, exams, student
where student.studentId=completedExams.studentId
    and completedExams.examId=exams.id
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you explicitly define the type of join relationships you are establishing between tables.  This will ensure you have the best performance possible from the queries and help ensure the database engine uses the best execution plan possible.  As it is written the performance of your query will suffer especially if you have a large number of records.  While it is true that the database engine may be able to correctly interpret the join based on the where clause this can lead to scale problems later down the road.

Also, the use of table aliases will go a long way to avoid the ambiguous column problem.

Here are some reference materials....

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187455(v=SQL.105).aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191517(v=SQL.105).aspx